# Moq and Async fun using LazyCache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock a function named GetOrAddAsync. It's defined as:

```
Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> addItemFactory, DateTimeOffset expires);
```

When I use it in my actual code I use it like:

```
DateTimeOffset cacheTimeout = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(config.CacheHours));
Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>> func = async () => await (from s in dbContext.Names select s.First).ToListAsync();

return await cache.GetOrAddAsync(key, func, cacheTimeout);
```

So basically if the key exists it will return what's in it and if not it'll create a key and fill it with data returned from the passed in Func<>.

My mocking attempt of this so far is as follows:

```
cache.Setup(x => x.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(async (string key, Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>> func, DateTimeOffset policy) =>
                    {
                        return await func.Invoke();
                    });
```

However, this is returning an error:

**Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEnumerable' because it's not a delegate type.**

My mind is ready to explode with this syntax :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReturnsAsync is not to be used when you have an async callback function, think of it more as doing `.ReturnsAsync(foo)` is just shorthand for `.Returns(Task.FromResult(foo))`. So you are trying to do is the same thing as

```
cache.Setup(x => x.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(async (string key, Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>> func, DateTimeOffset policy) =>
                    {
                        return await func.Invoke();
                    }));
```

Change to using a normal `Returns(` and your function should work fine.

```
cache.Setup(x => x.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>()))
            .Returns(async (string key, Func<Task<IEnumerable<int>>> func, DateTimeOffset policy) =>
                {
                    return await func.Invoke();
                });
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than having to mock the LazyCache API using Moq yourself why not just use the mock version provided by the framework? It just executes whatever your delegate to be cached is and never does any caching. Check out [MockCachingService.cs](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/blob/master/LazyCache/Mocks/MockCachingService.cs)

Comment: This isn't useful if you actually want to test the fact the caching is working

Comment: @johnstaveley that's true, but in that case you could also just use the real in-memory cache since it is fast reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Besides actually mocking the cache calls, I would keep the caching functionality by providing a [CachingService](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/blob/master/LazyCache/CachingService.cs) instance for the service under test.

Credit: [Codidact](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285541)